# How to send http file get content using Android and catch (display) the response (json-data)

Tags: php, android, json, http, file-get-contents

I'm developing my first android application which I need to fetch data stored at online server **(localhost for testing)** but I can't figure how to do it in android, I tried to read some resources here but am not able to use the codes as they are just been highlighted red and lack of experience in android.

If that is using PHP this is what I could have done but so far in android is not able to figure how to;

**PHP Begins**

```
<?php
     $feeds = @file_get_contents($mysrver_url); // in android am lost much here
     if($feeds)
     {
        $array = json_decode($feeds); // my data from server is already json
        if($array[success]){
            foreach($array[feeds] as $feed_key => $array_feed_data){
                echo "<div>";
                    echo "<span>" . $array[feeds][$feed_key][val1] . "<span>";
                    echo "<span>" . $array[feeds][$feed_key][val2] . "<span>";
                    echo "<span>" . $array[feeds][$feed_key][val3] . "<span>";
                    echo "<span> <a href='$downloadlink'>" Download "</a><span>";
                echo "</div>";  
            }               
        } else 
        {
            echo "No feeds available";  
        }        
     } else 
     {
        echo "No connection made"; // error message
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't started yet, I would look through the sample code for something that downloads text from the internet and start with that.

Comment: so far this seems can work on getting content of my www page 
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL("http://192.168.23.1");
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                     } catch {//error goes here }
with the above code am not able to get the content all am seeing are http responses like OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i get it right;

**import java.io.BufferedReader;**
**import java.io.InputStreamReader;**

```
URL url;
url = new URL("http://192.168.23.1");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String jsonArray = in.readLine().toString();
in.close();
```

**The response of the web is in String jsonArray**

I hope it may be useful to someone one day